# Vue 2.0 Laravel 5.3 array and object passsing via forEach

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I have the following child methods

```
methods:{
  selectedPC(selectedProductChoice){
    this.$parent.$children.forEach(choice=>{
      choice.isActive = (choice.id == selectedProductChoice.id)
    })
  }
}
```

and my child template is the following

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <li 
    class="product-choice" 
    :class="{'selected': productChoice.isActive}"
    @click.prevent="selectedPC(productChoice)"
    >
      ......
      ......
      ......
    </li>
  </transition>
</template>
```

and here is where the child `product-choices` is called by the the parent template

```
<ul class="product-choices" v-show="thumbnailHover">
   <product-choices v-for="(productChoice, index) in productChoices" :key="productChoice.id" :product="product" :product-choice="productChoice" :index="index"></product-choices>
</ul>
```

Not sure why but the choice in the `forEach` in child template is an object which does not allow me to read `choice.id` (`undefined` as I tried to `alert` it). Is it array object problem? I kind of follow the tabs tutorial from Vue 2 Laracast for you reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try `child.$data` to access the data associated with the child, like following:

```
methods:{
  selectedPC(selectedProductChoice){
    this.$parent.$children.forEach(choice=>{
      choice.$data.isActive = (choice.$data.id == selectedProductChoice.id)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: well it makes sense to me but it stays undefined for alert('choice.$data.id')